# MVC 6 Encryption URL Parameter post doesnt get actual value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am facing an issue when i am using encryption of parameter.

when I call.
`http://localhost:51836/en-US/Vehicles/Edit/s5XHf7R6YtM=`
it passes correct value of id after decryption.

I have store the actual Id into hidden field. 
 when I use

it stores the ecrypted value rather than decrypted value.

and if I am using simple
`<input asp-for="ID" type="hidden" value = '@Model.ID' />`
it stored decrypted value.

Now when i try to save the data, ID should be decrypted value should i get but it shows me 0 . I am not getting why this is happening. Is this because of ID same name of parameter and propertyName.

Please let me know if you have any solution,

Thanks
SAMIR

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to Base64 encoding, not encryption. What exactly is the parameter "encrypted" and "decrypted", update the question to be more clear.

Comment: Yes I am using Base64 encoding

Comment: Base64 is encoding, not encryption, pease change the question removing encryption. A correct title and question will help to get answers. As it is not it is confusing. Change "encryption" to "Base64 encoding".

Answer (score 0):

Base64 encoding includes three characters that can not be used in parts of a URL so the Base64 encoding needs to be URL escaped.

The troublesome characters are: '/', '+' and "=".

If the encoded value does not contain any of these characters in a part of the URL that disallows them the URL will work, otherwise it will fail. This is why for some values it works and for other values it fails.

See [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).